# core data fetch with filter

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to add a filter (boolean value) to a fetch in core data, but I'm not sure how.

The entity name is `Vinyl` and the attribute that I want to use to filter is called `wishlist` (true or false)

```
if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {
            if let vinyls = try? context.fetch(Vinyl.fetchRequest()) {
                if let theVinyls = vinyls as? [Vinyl] {
                    self.allVinyls = theVinyls
                    totalVinyls = theVinyls.count
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I filter for `wishlist == true` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an appropriate predicate.

All `if let`s are not necessary, the `viewContext` is supposed to be non-optional.

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let request : NSFetchRequest<Vinyl> = Vinyl.fetchRequest()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "wishlist == TRUE")
request.predicate = predicate
do {
  self.allVinyls = try context.fetch(request)
  totalVinyls = self.allVinyls.count
} catch { print(error) }
```